# Parse All Links That Contain A Specific Word In "href" Tag

Tags: php, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I need to parse all links of an HTML document that contain some word (it's always different).

Example:

```
<a href="/bla:bla">BLA</a>
<a href="/link:link">BLA</a>
<a href="/link:bla">BLA</a>
```

I only need the links with "href=/link: ...." what's the best way to go for it?

```
$html = "SOME HTLM ";
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    echo "<br> {$url->getAttribute('href')} , {$url->getAttribute('title')}";
    echo "<hr><br>";
}
```

In this example all links are shown, I need specific links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a condition.

```
<?php 
$lookfor='/link:';

foreach ($urls as $url){
    if(substr($url->getAttribute('href'),0,strlen($lookfor))==$lookfor){
        echo "<br> ".$url->getAttribute('href')." , ".$url->getAttribute('title');
        echo "<hr><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of first fetching all the a elements and then filtering out the ones you need you can query your document for those nodes directly by using [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
//a[contains(@href, "link:")]
```

This query will find *all a elements* in the document which *contain* the string *link:* in the *href attribute*.

To check whether the href attribute *starts with* link: you can do

```
//a[starts-with(@href, "link:")]
```

#### Full example ([demo](http://codepad.org/La2qW8qw)):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[contains(@href, "link:")]') as $a) {
    echo $a->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Please also see

- [Implementing condition in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448005/implementing-condition-in-xpath-and-xquery/3448050#3448050)
- [excluding URLs from path links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057676/excluding-urls-from-path-links/7058159#7058159)
- [PHP/XPath: find text node that "starts with" a particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822469/php-xpath-find-text-node-that-starts-with-a-particular-string/4822639#4822639)
- [PHP Xpath : get all href values that contain needle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392393/php-xpath-get-all-href-values-that-contain-needle)

for related questions.

*Note: marking this CW because of the many related questions*

Comment: Thank you.Would  you also explain what  "CW" is?

Comment: @Ron CW = Community Wiki. I dont get reputation from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $href = $url->getAttribute('href');
    if (preg_match("/^\/link:/",$href){
        $links[$url->getAttribute('title')] = $href;
    }
}
```

$links array contains all of the titles and href's that match.

Comment: Regular expressions are relatively expensive operations, you should avoid using them in loops if possible.  substr() is fine in this case.

Comment: True, but judging by his setup, I have a strange feeling it was going to get more complicated later.

Comment: No need to add complexity until it's really needed :)

Answer (score 0):

As getAttribute simply returns a string you only need to check what it starts with with strpos().

```
$href = $url -> getAttrubute ('href');
if (strpos ($href, '/link:') === 0)
{
    // Do your processing here
}
```