# Selecting a css class with xpath

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I want to select just a class on its own called .date

For some reason, I cannot get this to work. If anyone knows what is wrong with my code, it would be much appreciated.

```
@$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple
$images = $xml->xpath('//[@class="date"]');                             
foreach ($images as $img)
{
    echo  $img." ";
}
```

Comment: and what about piece of html ? ( Prefer to show us simpleXml output from asXML() as it is nearer to xpath )

Comment: if there is multiple classes you need to do `contains(@class, 'date')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Parse All Links That Contain A Speciffic Word In "href" Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208240/php-parse-all-links-that-contain-a-speciffic-word-in-href-tag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath: How to match attributes that contain a certain string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string)

Comment: @Gordon's answer is dangerous, if the class attribute is "datetime" it would also match. user716736's answer is more complete.

Comment: @NielsBom *dangerous* is a rather odd choice of words. Also, my answer clearly states it will find all links that contain (note the emphasis) the search word. And it doesn't change that this question is a dupe of many.

Comment: Dupe:sure. Dangerous: I'll rephrase that to: you might get more than you would expect. And sorry but I don't think your comment ("if there is...'date')") is clear.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

I want to write the canonical answer to this question because the answer above has a problem.

### Our problem

The **CSS** selector:

```css
.foo
```

will select any element that has the class **foo**.

**How do you do this in XPath?**

Although XPath is more powerful than CSS, **XPath doesn't have a native equivalent of a CSS class selector**.  However, there is a solution.

### The right way to do it

The equivalent selector in **XPath** is:

```bash
//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ")]
```

The function [normalize-space](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) strips leading and trailing whitespace (and also replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space).

(In a more general sense) this is also the equivalent of the CSS selector:

```css
*[class~="foo"]
```

which will match any element whose **class** attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to **foo**.

### A couple of obvious, but wrong ways to do it

The XPath selector:

```bash
//*[@class="foo"]
```

doesn't work!  because it won't match an element that has more than one class, for example

```html
<div class="foo bar">
```

It also won't match if there is any extra whitespace around the class name:

```
<div class="  foo ">
```

The 'improved' XPath selector

```bash
//*[contains(@class, "foo")]
```

doesn't work either! because it wrongly matches elements with the class **foobar**, for example

```html
<div class="foobar">
```

Credit goes to this fella, who was the earliest published solution to this problem that I found on the web:
http://dubinko.info/blog/2007/10/01/simple-parsing-of-space-seprated-attributes-in-xpathxslt/

Comment: What's the need for normalize-space?

Comment: "the answer above" probably refers to MrGlass's.

Comment: Is this possible `<div class="foo\tbar">`? I mean, class names separated by a tab.

Comment: I think `*[class~="foo"]` misses the `@`. Should be `*[@class~="foo"]`.

Comment: but <div class="group-conditions"/> and <div class="condition"/> is the same for
$x('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "condition")]')

Comment: @NielsBom - How do we get around the contains limitation mentioned at the end ? Use css selector instead ? The xpath contains-token given in another answer does not work in the latest chrome.

Comment: @testerjoe2 did you try `//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ")]` ?

Answer (score 13):

`//[@class="date"]` is not a valid xpath.

Try `//*[@class="date"]`, or if you know it is an image, `//img[@class="date"]`

Answer (score 7):

*XPath 3.1* introduces a function [contains-token](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-contains-token) and thus finally solves this ‘officially’. It is designed to [support classes](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=22258).

**Example:**

`//*[contains-token(@class, "foo")]`

This function makes sure that white space (not only  (U+0020)) is handled correctly, works in case of class name repetition, and generally covers the edge cases.

---

**Note:** As of today (2016-12-13) XPath 3.1 has status of *Candidate Recommendation*.

Comment: It does not work in today's latest chrome. Until it works, how do we get around the limitation that //*[contains(@class, "foo")] will also select any class that contains foo, such as foobar, fooz etc.

Answer (score 3):

In XPath 2.0 you can:

`//*[count(index-of(tokenize(@class, '\s+' ), 'foo')) = 1]`

as stated by Christian Weiske in:
https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/XPath%3A%20Select%20element%20by%20class.htm

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to be implemented by chrome as of 6/12/2017.  based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(XML)#Query_technologies it seems to be lacking pretty much across the board

Answer (score 1):

HTML allows case-insensitive element and attribute names and then class is a space separated list of class-names. Here we go for a `img` tag and the `class` named `date`:

```
//*['IMG' = translate(name(.), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')]/@*['CLASS' = translate(name(.), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(.), ' '), concat(' ', 'date', ' '))]
```

See as well: [CSS Selector to XPath conversion](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/css-selector-to-xpath-conversion/)

Answer (score 1):

BEWARE OF MINUS SIGNS IN TEMPLATE !!! If you are querying for "my-ownclass" in DOM:

```
<ul class="my-ownclass"><li>...</li></ul>
<ul class="someother"><li>...</li></ul>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query(".//ul[contains(@class, 'my-ownclass')]"); // This will NOT behave as expected! This will strangely match all the <ul> elements in DOM.
$nodes = $finder->query(".//ul[contains(@class, 'ownclass')]"); // This will match the element.
```