# Is it possible to access a 'style' type css selector when using cheezy's page-object and watir?

Tags: cucumber, watir, pageobjects

In my page.rb, I'm using `div(:select, :css => 'div.active[style="display: block;"]')` which is giving me the error - Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException.

In the console, `document.querySelector("div.active[style='display: block;']")` returns the object properly. I'm not too sure where to look in the documentation, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the page-object gem code, I do not believe that the page-object gem supports :css locators for watir-webdriver. At least it is not included in the watir_finders method - see [element.rb](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/elements/element.rb) and [div.rb](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/elements/div.rb). I am guessing that the reason is due to watir-webdriver's current limitation that :css locators can only be used when using the `element` method - see [watir-webdriver's issue 124](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/124).

**Solution 1 - Use a Block**

However, you could workaround these issues by defining the div in your page object with a block.

Assuming the html:

```
<div class="active" style='display: block;'>text</div>
```

The following worked for me:

```
div(:select){ browser.element(:css => 'div.active[style="display: block;"]') }
```

**Solution 2 - Use Xpath**

Alternatively, you could convert your css locator to an xpath locator:

```
div(:select2, :xpath => '//div[@class="active" and @style="display: block;"]')
```

Note that if you go this way, you might want to look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath), which talks about using a more robust locator for the class.