# Finding XPath for text in div following input

Tags: html, xpath

I got an issue reading XPath. Need some help/advise from experts.

Part of my HTML is below:

```
<div class = "input required_field">
    <div class="rounded_corner_error">
        <input id="FnameInput" class="ideField" type="text" value="" name="first_name>
           <div class ="help-tooltip">LOGIN BACK TO MAIN</div>
           <div class="error-tooltip">
```

I need to find the XPath of the text message (LOGIN BACK TO MAIN)

Using Firebug I find the XPath

```
("//html/body/div/div[5]/div/div/form/fieldset/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div");
```

But using above XPath I can read only class = `help-tooltip` but I need to read `LOGIN BACK TO MAIN`.

Comment: The HTML you have posted is invalid (the `name` attribute of the `input` element is unclosed). You have also indented the last two `divs` as though they are children of the `input`, but that would be invalid HTML and is probably not representative of your structure. If you are feeding HTML (which is not valid XML) to a system that is only XML-aware, you may have problems.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `/text()` on the end of the xpath you have.

Answer (score 3):

It does not really look like your XPath matches your XHTML element.

You should try something simpler and more generic, such as:

```
//div[@class="help-tooltip"]/text()
```

See [Selecting a css class with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8808921/850848).

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```sh
# Selecting the div element
//input[@id="FnameInput"]/following-sibling::div[@class="help-tooltip"]

# Selecting the text content of the div
//input[@id="FnameInput"]/following-sibling::div[@class="help-tooltip"]/text()
```

…since a syntactically-valid HTML document will have a unique `id` attribute, and as such that's a pretty strong anchor point.

Note that the latter expression will select the text **node**, not the text string content of that node; you need to extract the value of the text node if you want the string. How you do that depends on what tools you are using:

- In JavaScript/DOM that would be the [`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue) property of the text node.
- For [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) that would be the [`.content`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-content) method.
- *…but I have no idea what technology you are using your XPath with.*