# Can't find error with xpath query, `undefined method DOMDocument`

Tags: php, xpath

I'm getting a `Call to undefined method DOMDocument::xpath()` on the `$level1` line of my code:

```
          $doc = new DOMDocument();
          $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
          $doc->loadHTML($html);
          $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
          $level1 = $doc->xpath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " category-wrap ")]/h2/a');
```

Here is the html it's loading (via `file_get_contents()`):

```
<div class="category-wrap">
   <a href='#'>LINK</a>
   <h2><a href="#">Trying to get this....</a></h2>
   <p>A description</p>

</div>
```

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath) as a reference for the xpath query.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your query, there only lacks understanding of the error message. it's easy to fix, just take the right object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't such method like `xpath` in DOMDocument.
See http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

You need to initialize an instance of DOMXpath to use xpath queries

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
```

or alternatively call the method on the SimpleXMLObject you've created

```
$level1 = $xml->xpath('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " category-wrap ")]/h2/a');
```

Comment: So would future queries then be `$xpath('query');` ?

Comment: With the first option it will be $xpath->xpath('query');