# get a data with HTMLagilitypack from a span

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to catch some data from a website using HtmlAgilityPack. 
The data is stored in an object with the property `class="addresscolor__"`. But the problem is that there is more than one class with this name. And I want to know is there any way to get this data from a specific class with that value, using "Start with" or "Contained.." or some thing like this ?

HTML Code :

```
<p class="addresscolor__">
    <span>Phone:</span>
    33875362 ، 22356341
    <br />
</p>

<p class="addresscolor__">
    <span>mobile:</span>
    09125231827
    <br />
</p>
```

I use thhis code:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='addresscolor__']");
```

The other thing is, that this class contained span tag and with these codes I catch the whole `<p>` tag values, but I want a number only in "Mobile" span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding this paragraph:

```
//p[@class='addresscolor__' and contains(span, 'mobile:')]
```

For limiting to its text node (the phone number):

```
//p[@class='addresscolor__' and contains(span, 'mobile:')]/text()
```

For further stripping whitespace:

```
normalize-space(//p[@class='addresscolor__' and contains(span, 'mobile:')]/text())
```

For matching HTML classes, also consider [a node can have multiple classes and how to deal with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath/9133579#9133579).