# XSLT: select elements that have multiple @class values based off of 1 of those values

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have an XML document which uses multiple @class values, like below:

```
<html>
     <head>
        <title>This is the title.</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class="sect1 rights">
             <p>This is the first paragraph.</p>
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

However, my XSLT below does not work when both @class values are present. It will only work if `<div class="rights">`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@class='rights']">
    <p>Rights have not cleared to show this material.</p>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't think this is a priority of templates problem (from the identity template) as I'm not getting a warning of that. Is there a way to select this content? I won't always know what other class values are assigned besides "rights" so I can't use `*[@class='sect1 rights']` as sect1 will change throughout the document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting a css class with xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Definitely works for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `tokenize()`. This a much simpler form of the `concat()` solution that [@user3016153 gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133579/2363712) (both forms are much more accurate than the simple `contains()`).

```
<xsl:template match="*[tokenize(@class,'\s')='rights']">
    <p>Rights have not cleared to show this material.</p>
</xsl:template>
```

It is also very easy to extend if you want to match more than one possible class:

```
<xsl:template match="*[tokenize(@class,'\s')=('rights','otherclass')]">
    <p>Rights have not cleared to show this material.</p>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the "class" attribute has only a **single** value: the string "sect1 rights". If you want to test for the inclusion of the string "rights" in that value, use:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,'rights')]">
```

or perhaps:

```
contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' rights ')
```

if you want to ensure the presence of "rights" as a word (i.e. not as part of "copyrights", for example).

Comment: Thanks, also saw this on the link above. Will uses <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, 'rights')]">

Comment: @user2093335 If you use `*[contains(@class, 'rights')]` it will also match an element whose `class` is `newrights`, for example.