# how to choose a complex class?

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x, lxml

please help to solve the problem.

html:

```
<form class="variants" action="/cart">
    <a class="thumb fancybox image_outer" href="products/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-black--space-gray-chernyj" data-fancybox-group="gallery5">
        <img src="http://first-store.ru/files/products/iphone%205S%20black_1.100x112.jpg?16ef5c4132fc88594851f92ccc2f3437" alt="Apple iPhone 5s 16GB Black &amp; Space Gray (Чёрный)" title="Apple iPhone 5s 16GB Black &amp; Space Gray (Чёрный)">
    </a>

    <h1>
        <a class="name_mark" data-product="1075" href="products/apple-iphone-5s-16gb-black--space-gray-chernyj">Apple iPhone 5s 16GB Black &amp; Space Gray (Чёрный)</a>
    </h1>

    <span class="price price_mark price_value">26 990&nbsp;<span class="currency">руб</span>

        <input id="variants_2927" name="variant" value="2927" type="radio" class="variant_radiobutton" checked="" style="display:none;">

        <input class="button buy buy_button buy_button_catalog" type="submit" value="Купить" data-result-text="Добавлено">
    </span>     
</form>
```

## 1 code not worked:

```
price = article.xpath('span[@class="price"]/span[@class="currency"]/text()')[0].strip()
if price:
    print(price)
```

## 2 code worked:

```
price = article.xpath('span/span[@class="currency"]/text()')[0].strip()
if price:
    print(price)
```

but I need to find a "price" on the model # 1. the problem is that the attribute class is composed of several values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting a css class with xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[@class="price"]` matches only when the `class` attribute value is exactly `price`.

You need xpath similar to following:

```
price = article.xpath('span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " price ")]/span[@class="currency"]/text()')[0].strip()
```

Maybe you'd better to use [css selector](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html):

```
price = article.cssselect('span.price>span.currency')[0].text.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an xpath like this one(just selects the price span):

```
article.xpath('span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " price ")]')
```

Another possibility is using a css selector:

```
article.cssselect('span.price')
```