# Element is no longer attached to the Dom error for link

Tags: selenium, xpath

I try to get a href from an anchor according to linkText given with func param (for example here Westwood or Linda).
In the code below I changed classes values (cause of company info), but beside thats the code. For each `<tr>` the hrefs are identical for both `<td>`, but different from `<tr>` to `<tr>`
I get the 1st href with:

```
driver.findElemnt(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'class Name of a']").getAttribute("href")
```

or the same with:

```
xpath="//a[@class = 'class Name of a'][1]";
```

but when I go:

```
"//a[@class = 'class Name of a'][2]"  or 3 or 4...
```

or when I use:

```
By.partialLinkText
```

It fails, so I never get beyond the 1st `<td>` of the first `<tr>`.

> The Error: oopenqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : Element
>   is no longer attached to the Dom.

The Elements are visible all the time, so its not a visibility problem.

This is the html:

```
<tr class="Class name for tr here">       
    <td headers="description _ CustomerList:lastName">
        <a href="some path index=0" class="class Name of a">Westwood</a>
    </td>

    <td headers="description _CustomerList:firstName">   
        <a href="some path index=0" class="class Name of a">Linda</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please, at least have a short glimpse at the preview to realize all your HTML tags are (now have been) missing...

Comment: General hint for matching HTML class attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath/9133579#9133579

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to retrieve the second anchor tag within *the same parent* (in the example document: table cells).

Instead of

```
//a[@class = 'class Name of a'][2]
```

query the second anchor tag in the whole document:

```
(//a[@class = 'class Name of a'])[2]
```

---

Some more examples how to use positional predicates (I omitted the class predicate here):

- Anchor tags from all second table cells per row:

  ```
  //td[2]/a
  ```
- Second anchor tag per row:

  ```
  //tr//a[2]
  ```

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked. I gave up the class attribute, went up to the table attribute and retrive it correctly. works!