# Xpath expression to get an optional element in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, github, scrapy

By optional, I mean the element could not exist.

I have a spider for GitHub, I am trying to get the primary Language for a rep

```html
<div class="repository-lang-stats">
    <ol class="repository-lang-stats-numbers">
      <li>
          <a href="/scrapy/scrapy/search?l=python">
            <span class="color-block language-color" style="background-color:#3581ba;"></span>
            <span class="lang">Python</span>
            <span class="percent">99.1%</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <span class="other">
            <span data-lang="Other" class="color-block language-color"></span>
            <span class="lang">Other</span>
            <span class="percent">0.9%</span>
          </span>
      </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

In the example (source of [this repo](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy)) above I need to get "**Python**", from first

```
<span class="lang">
```

But my problem is for some repo, like an empty one, there is no

```
<span class="lang">
```

tag, or

```
<ol class="repository-lang-stats-numbers">
```

tag. How do I get over this?

Comment: solved by adding code to exception block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for finding the list of languages, take the first list item and retrieve the first span, jumping over possible anchor tags (they seem to be missing for some low-frequency languages).

```
//ol[@class="repository-lang-stats-numbers"]/li[1]//span[@class="lang"]
```

An empty result will indicate that no language data is available.

Some remarks:

- To be more specific, you could prepend `div[@class="repository-lang-stats"]` as first axis step, but I don't think it will be necessary.
- We're [matching class attributes, watch out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath/9133579#9133579)!
- To return only the text value, append `/text()` to the query.

Anyway: **Github offers an** [**API** that also lets you query repository languages](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages). Better use this instead of scraping the site. APIs are fast, easy to use and stable; web sites are front end code that change often and will break your XPath queries.

You can query it by accessing a special URI (for example https://api.github.com/repos/scrapy/scrapy/languages) that will return a JSON object that can be easily parsed and sorted:

```
{
  "Shell": 1733,
  "Python": 1195439,
  "CSS": 9681
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is `div/ol/li/a/span[@class="lang"]/text()`. It will return nothing in case anything along the path is missing.