# Scrapy -- scrappy not returning information from a html tag

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying of scraping a website, I'm using for scraping scrapy , but when I make the  scraping the html data, the html tag that I need for obtain any  data,
I'm using  xpath for obtain of data the this tag but this not  return nothing

This the website ("http://www.exito.com/products/0000293501259261/Arroz+Fortificado?cid=&page=") and this is the part of Html  that  i'm scraping

```
<div class="pdpInfoProductPrice">
    <meta itemprop="currency" content="COP">
<h4 itemprop="price" class="price">
   $5.350</h4>
</div>
```

I need  use scrapy on  tag h4 for obtain the price , but  When I'm scraping   only obtain  This class is empty, the class does not have any tag inside
This should be a simple thing to do, but I can not get get the price in any way

I was  using some xpath  on  the page for  I can obtain  the price

```
sel.xpath('[@id="plpContent"]/div[3]/div[5]/h4').extract()
sel.xpath('//*[@id="atg_store_two_column_main"]/div[2]').extract()
//*[@id="mainWhiteContent"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/h4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first request, the web page asks for your region and stores it in a cookie.

[image: Example dialog]

You can reproduce this by either deleting cookies or using another browser/private browsing session.

To workaround, you will have to send the cookie with name `selectedCity` and a region code like `AR`. Use something like this when creating the request:

```
request = Request(
            url="http://www.exito.com/products/0000293501259261/Arroz+Fortificado?cid=&page=",
            cookies={'selectedCity': 'AR'}
          )
```

For the XPath expression, I'd go for

```
//div[@class='pdpInfoProductPrice']/h4[@itemprop='price']/text()
```

Also take this answer on matching HTML classes into account: [Selecting a css class with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath/9133579#9133579).

Comment: Thanks,you're right but I'm trying with this request but is impossible obtain this value

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xpath:

```
sel.xpath("//div[@id='mainWhite']/div[@id='mainWhiteContent']/div[@class='row-fluid'][2]/div[@class='span9 widthCarulla']/div[@class='row-fluid']/div[@class='pdpProduct span12']/div[@class='pdpInfoProduct pull-left']/div[@class='pdpInfoProductPrices']/div[@class='pdpInfoProductPrice']/h4[@class='priceOffer']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: thanks,I tried this, but it does not return anything 
I change the xpath to return some data,

sel.xpath("//div[@id='mainWhite']/div[@id='mainWhiteContent']/div[@class='row-fluid'][2]/div[@class='span9 widthCarulla']").extract()

sel.xpath("//div[@id='mainWhite']/div[@id='mainWhiteContent']").extract()

then I copy all the html that returns me. and then I open it in a browser but I do not see the product price, 
this has been happening to me with queries I miss to get the price. 
I'm thinking it might be that this meta tag inside the tag <div, the problem