# Remove class name from tag nodes using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need to get rid of specific class names from html, for example:

```
<table class="removeme"></table>
```

I need a code snipped who can remove specified class "removeme" and html after cleaning will look like this:

```
<table></table>
```

Also bear in mind that passed html can contain something like:

```
<table class="removeme leaveme"></table>
```

and after cleaning it should appear as:

```
<table class="leaveme"></table>
```

Comment: You should look into XPath expressions as you can write an XPath to return nodes that have a class associated. Using that with the `.DocumentNode.SelectNodes()` function will give you a collection of nodes that you need to remove the attribute from.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to address this in two steps, first get all nodes having only 'removeme` class attribute, then remove the entire class attribute from them :

```
//*[normalize-space(@class)='removeme']
```

Then in the next step, get all nodes having `removeme` class and some other classes, then strip out `removeme` from the class attribute :

```
//*[
     normalize-space(@class)!='removeme'
        and
     contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' removeme ')
   ]
```

the first condition in the XPath above means get all nodes that isn't processed in the step 1, and the 2nd condition is [the equivalent XPath for css selector `.removeme`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133579/2998271)

Here is the complete console example :

```
var xml = @"<root>
    <table class=""removeme""></table>
    <table class=""removeme leaveme""></table>
    <table class="" removeme ""></table>
</root>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(xml);
var removemeOnly = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[normalize-space(@class)='removeme']");
foreach (HtmlNode node in removemeOnly)
{
    node.Attributes["class"].Remove();
}
var containsRemoveme =
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[normalize-space(@class)!='removeme' and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' removeme ')]");
foreach (HtmlNode node in containsRemoveme)
{
    node.Attributes["class"].Value = node.Attributes["class"].Value.Replace("removeme", "");
}
//print formatted HTML output (don't use this for non XML-compliant HTML)
Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Parse(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml));
```