# get the class name inside div element by xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I want to get the class name inside the div element by xpath.

```
<div class="indicator true"></div>
```

And I want to check if the class nams equals to "indicator true". Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match attributes that contain a certain string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the class value of the div element by using the WebElement.getAttribute() - Method.

Your Problem is to get the div element without the class as part of the selector.

I suggest to add an id attribut to the div and select the div by id selector. Then you can check class value.

`WebElement divElem = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"))
assert divElem.getAttribute("class").equals("indicator true");`

Comment: It works!! thanks! Can I ask (just in case you might know) How can I get the value isnude the div element? for example how to get the value1 inside <div id=1> value1<div>?

Comment: use divElem.getText(), it returns the visible Text inside.

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to check if the class nams equals to "indicator true". Any help?

Yes, there is help.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'indicator true']")) .click();
```

That said, I am not sure what your intention is. Because you also say:

> I want to get the class name inside the div element by xpath.

The path expression above returns a `div` element, not the class name.

Comment: Actually I do not know how to get the class name and compare it by if statement. I edited my question. What I wrote was just a try I did.

Answer (score 0):

//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ")]

source : [Selecting a css class with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the getAttribute() and enter the identify name in the brackets 
this will return you the identify value.
the following code should return you "indicator true":

```
assert divElem.getAttribute("class");
```