# Traversing with XPath?

Tags: html, css, xpath, traversal

I am looking for a faster way to grab contents with xpath.

I read this post:
[Selecting a css class with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath)

put the first responses "class" selector in my project, as..

```
//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " attr-price ")]
```

which works great. It returns to me all the elements with the class "attr-price", and I can even do something like a compound selector by doing..

```
//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " attr-price second-class")]
```

However, the part of this I do not like is the //*. This makes XPath go through all nodes, and is decreasing my sites performance pretty significantly. I read on W3schools about the different types of selectors and have tried using / and // instead of //*, however none of these work. The attr-price elements are all within a `<ul>` would like to do something analagous to..

```
/ul/[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " attr-price ")]
```

this way I am hitting each of the UL's instead of every single element, and then searching for my class there, kind of like if I was using jQuery's

```
$('ul').find('.attr-price')
```

Any input is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you running this within the browser, or is it something you are doing server-side? In the latter case, what technology are you using? XPath processors are not all the same.

Comment: I am running this on the Moovweb platform, on a proxy with a language called Tritium

Comment: In that case, sorry, I can't help you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath equivalent to

```
$('ul').find(...)
```

would be

```
//ul//...
```

So your XPath would become

```
//ul//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " attr-price ")]
```

Whether that is actually any faster depends on the XPath processor and the DOM model implementation, I guess.

On a different note, your compound selector

```
//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "),
       " attr-price second-class")]
```

will only work if the class attribute happens to contain both of those classes *in the right order*. If you want a compound selector that doesn't rely on the order in which the classes are listed (as it wouldn't in CSS), you'd need to use something like

```
//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " attr-price ")
 and contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " second-class ")]
```

which is pretty clunky.
Remember that if you have access to XPath 2.0, you can use `tokenize()` instead. For that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165195/423105

Comment: Thanks LarsH, I am familiar that it needs to be in the right order. I will check to see if I have access to xpath 2.0, I think this would be the way if possible.