# How can I find an element by CSS class nested inside other elements with XPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to extract all links that are in complex selectors like - `.timestream .ui-ContentBottom h1 a`. I know how to do it with simple links like just a single selector like `a` :

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML($html);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $nodes = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
 foreach($nodes as $href) {
   echo $href->nodeValue;
 }
```

I am new to xPath so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following XPath expression should work for you:

```
//*[contains(@class, "timestream")]//*[contains(@class, "ui-ContentBottom")]//h1//a/@href
```

The problem here is that *XPath does not have a native `class` selector.* In other words, `contains(@class, "smth")` is not exactly the same as `.smth`, but, in practice, it usually works for matching a single class in a multi-valued class attribute value. See also:

- [Selecting a css class with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath)

Comment: Could you please provide a link where I can read more about using complex xPath queries? Thanks :)

Comment: @SanJeetSingh cannot recall anything specific, just google search the XPath tutorials and practice and practice more! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

[xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) lets you search a document such as an xml or html file.

xpath will not show classes in the path, but will show ids with an `@` symbol.

The xpath can be obtained in a few ways. One way in Chrome is to view the source of an element, right-click it and click `Copy XPath`.

When I do this on the the textarea box I am answering this question in, I receive the following xpath ::

```
//*[@id="wmd-input"]
```

Do not let that confuse you though. Here is a more simplistic example

```
/html/body
```

This is the xpath of the body element.

I wrote a small function that can help you turn xpaths into elements.

```
function xpath(path){
    for (var found, x = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null), result = []; found = x.iterateNext();) {
        result.push(found);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This function produces the following when running it against this textarea ::

```
xpath('//*[@id="wmd-input"]');
[<textarea id=​"wmd-input" class=​"wmd-input processed" name=​"post-text" cols=​"92" rows=​"15" tabindex=​"101" data-min-length>​</textarea>​]
```

Now that you have the element you can modify it like this example :

```
var test = xpath('/html/body');
test[0].innerHTML='bye';
```