# file get contents + preg match

Tags: php, html, class, file-get-contents

i try to return a number on a div , i want to have the "01 55 33 44"

```
     <div data-phone="01 55 33 44" class="agency_phone ">
     Phone
     </div>
```

I have try :

```
   $url = "myurl"; 
    $raw = file_get_contents($url); 
    preg_match('/<div data-phone="(.*)"class="agency_phone "/isU',$raw,$output); 
    echo $output[1];
```

I have no return, 
somone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate your code and  problems for the better understanding.

Comment: i try to do my best, just i want to retrieve the phone number.

Comment: `data-phone="([^"]+)" class`

Comment: But it's correct to use dom parser to do the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.php` file have following content.

```
<?php
   $url = "test.php"; 
   echo $raw = file_get_contents($url); 
   preg_match('/data-phone="(.*)" class/', $raw, $output);
   echo $output[1];
?>
```

And other file `source.php` which have html tags.

```
<div data-phone="01 55 33 44" class="agency_phone ">
  Phone
</div>
```

It will return followig array

```
Array
(
  [0] => data-phone="01 55 33 44" class
  [1] => 01 55 33 44
)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that regex-based solutions often require maintenance to adapt to tiny formatting changes in source HTML (just imagine they swap `data-phone` and `class` or insert another attribute in between). And of course they will always fail in edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, your regexp expects exactly zero spaces after the attribute, thus it won't match your actual HTML with exactly one space:

```
/<div data-phone="(.*)"class="agency_phone "
<div data-phone="01 55 33 44" class="agency_phone ">
```

In any case it's very hard to write a decent HTML parser from scratch using regular expressions. The easiest way is DOM and XPATH, e.g.:

```
<?php

$html = '
    <div data-phone="01 55 33 44" class="agency_phone ">
     Phone
     </div>
     <p>Unrelated</p>
     <div>Still unrealted</div>
        <div data-phone="+34 947 854 712" class="agency_phone ">
          Phone
          </div>

';

$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$phones = $xpath->query('//div/@data-phone');
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    var_dump($phone->value);
}
```

```
string(11) "01 55 33 44"
string(15) "+34 947 854 712"
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález what would be the expression be if I wish to get the data-phone of a specific class?

Comment: //div[@class="classname"]/@data-phone

Comment: Hum, filtering by class name in XPATH is not straightforward. After all it's a language that was developed with XML in mind, not HTML. You can check [Selecting a css class with xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath) for some suggestions (accepted answer is just awesome).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for the info, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is it the missing space?

[edit]
put full files here for reproduction purposes
[/edit]

This works:

```
// file url.html
<div data-phone="01 55 33 44" class="agency_phone ">
     Phone
     </div>
```

and:

```
<?php
// file test.php
$raw = file_get_contents('url.html');
preg_match('/data-phone="(.*)" class/',$raw,$output);
echo $output[1]; // 01 55 33 44
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul, but no return, blank page.

Comment: return NULL on the page

Comment: i updated the example to include everything you need to test it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Tested with a html file on local host, seems to work fine.

```
<?php
$url = "myurl"; 
$subject = file_get_contents($url); 
$pattern='<div data-phone="(.*)" class="agency_phone ">';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $output);
echo $output[1];    
?>
```