# How to check variable against a set of values in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following condition to test

```
<xsl:if test="   $Occupation='5' 
              or $Occupation='7'  
              or $Occupation='N' 
              or $Occupation='M' 
              or $Occupation='J' 
              or $Occupation='V' 
              or $Occupation='W'">
  <xsl:value-of select="'Accounts'"/>        
</xsl:if>
```

Is there a way to check like this?

```
<xsl:if test="$occupation contains('5','7','N','W','J','M')">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming everything in your list is a single character:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($occupation) = 1 and contains('57NWJM', $occupation)">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Accounts'"/>        
</xsl:if>
```

If the entries are longer than one character, you can use a separation character.  This character must of course not appear in any of the values in your list.  With a space as separation character, things might look like:

```
<xsl:if test="not(contains($occupation, ' ')) and contains(' foo bar baz ', concat(' ', $occupation, ' '))">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Accounts'"/>        
</xsl:if>
```

Make sure you don't forget those padding spaces before `foo` and after `baz`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
<xsl:if test="contains('57NMJ', $Occupation)">
```

but this would also return true when `$Occupation` = "7N", for example.

To protect against that, you can use:

```
<xsl:if test="contains('|5|7|N|M|J|', concat('|', $Occupation, '|'))">
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way round might work...

```
<xsl:if test="contains('57NWJM',$Occupation)">
```

Answer (score 0):

### XSLT 2.0

You can do this much more cleanly in XSLT 2.0:

```
$occupation = ('5','7','N','M','J','V','W')
```

### XSLT 1.0

For *single-character* value cases such as yours, this XPath 1.0 expression,

```
translate($occupation,'7NMJVW','555555')='5'
```

will return true when `$occupation` is `5`, `7`, `N`, `M`, `J`, `V`, or `W` as requested.

For *single- or multi-character* value cases, see [Thomas W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845604/290085) or [michael.hor257k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845546/290085), which employ a technique often used to [test `@class` attribute values safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath):

```
contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " target ")]
```