# Clicking all elements with matching class

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selinium. There is a table (inside another table) that I want to click each `<td>click here</td>` with a matching class value (note the text between opening and closing `td` will change but is irrelevant for matching purposes). The class value I'm trying to match is `open`. [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath) I learn the right way is with `//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " open ")]`

This seems to work but just for one random cell. How do I make it click all? I was planning on accomplishing this first and repeating the step, but it may be worth noting that the script should also do the same for class value `available` and not just `open` Is there away to do logical or?

TL;DR I want to click everything with `<td class="open">...</td>`
 and
`<td class="available">...</td>` where `...` is example text that will vary but should be ignored.

Comment: So is it `<td>click here</td>` or `<td class=" open ">click here</td>` ?

Comment: @Andersson `<td class=" open ">click here</td>` but the text (e.g. `click here`) changes, so the thing being matched is the `open`. Sorry if this was confusing, I'm having trouble being clear.

Answer (score 3):

Get all elements and store them in a List, then iterate over them and click the buttons in sequence.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " open ")]"));
for(WebElement webelement : list) {
       // webelement Click the button here
}
```

Comment: How can this be added to Selenium IDE, FireFox add-on?

Comment: The IDE plugin is limited when it comes to these type of more advanced operations. There might be a way of creating a loop, check if the element class match and then click it..  Start use a programming language and the selenium api is my tip if you really want to be able to solve problems like this. Otherwise someone else have to answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

To get all elements, you should use `driver.FindElements`. Make sure it's what you used, not `driver.FindElement`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following `XPath`:

```
//td[normalize-space(@class)="open" or normalize-space(@class)="available"]
```

This should match both `<td class=" open ">...</td>` and
`<td class=" available ">...</td>`

Comment: I guess my actual question is how to iterate over each returned result. I'm using Selenium IDE and I have that in the target, and the command is `click` but it only clicks one. And I want it to click each one that is matched.

Comment: I guess you can use `while` loop for this purpose. Check this http://www.testingdiaries.com/selenium-ide-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Use following approach may help you -

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

for(WebElement element:allElements)
{
    if(element.getAttribute("class").contains("open"))
    {
        // manipulate with <td> tag data 
    }
}
```

Comment: How can this be added to Selenium IDE, FireFox add-on?

Comment: I guess there is no way to do the same logic in 'Selenium IDE' but some additional plugins are there to manage conditions and looping

Comment: If Selenium IDE is too weak, what else should be used to run the source code? Is the normal approach to write another program e.g. Java and use it to run Selenium?

Comment: Yes Selenium webdriver is the best option to do that. You can choose your preferred language and  manage your logic what you want to do browser.