# DomXPath - How can I scrape an article tag?

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument, domxpath

Let's say I'm scraping this code (keep in mind that this **article** is wrapped in other tags):

```
<article class="offer-item">
    <h3>A Title</h3>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="offer-item-title">Content that I want</span>
    </a>
</article>
```

I have the following code for scraping the above code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("URL");
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$listing_url = $xpath->query("//article[@class='offer-item']//span[@class='offer-item-title']");
```

But it isn't working and I know in fact that it is because of the article tag. Because if I remove it and leave it like this it works:

```
$listing_url = $xpath->query("//span[@class='offer-item-title']");
```

Thanks to whoever can help me! Really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't expect any problem with that xpath. How  does it not work?

Comment: Does the `<article>` have multiple css classes by any chance? If so, you [cannot match it by simply doing `[@class='offer-item']`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9133579).

Comment: Yeah that was it guys. It had more than one class. Thanks a lot!