# Stuck trying to select an html element of a given class with xpath, where am I wrong?

Tags: html, css, xpath

Having done [research on selecting an html element of a given class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath), I'm stuck being
unable to select a `table` element with a class named `"treasuries-table"`
from https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/treasuries/. I've noticed that there is

`<table class="treasuries-index treasuries-table treasuries-table--smaller">`

on the page but it is not my target, only

`<table class="treasuries-table">`

is.
I've tried

`//table[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " treasuries-table ")]`

as well as [the less verbose, but not necessarily correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath/9133579#9133579),

`//table[@class="treasuries-table"]`

, all this to no avail.
Where am I wrong? I usually try first to find elements with this [online tester](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html), might it be the tester's fault?
P.S. Apologies if it does seem as a duplicate but the solutions mentioned in similar questions does not seem to work for me.

Comment: what language you doing this in?

Comment: Python and selenium. But I usually try first to find elements with this [online tester](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,`'//table[contains(@class,"treasuries-table")]'` is selecting 5 tables but '//table[@class="treasuries-index treasuries-table treasuries-table--smaller")]'  is selecting the first table which is equivalent to (//table[contains(@class,"treasuries-table")])[1]

Try:

```
'//table[contains(@class,"treasuries-table")]'
```

Comment: `'//table[contains(@class,"treasuries-table")]'` does not work.

Comment: @JohnSmith: this XPath  should work. Something else in your code is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use xpath here? Or even Selenium for that matter? I'd also consider using `pandas` to let that parse the `<table>` tags. This returns the 4 tables with the `treasuries-table` class. I'm just printing out the 1st one here.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/treasuries/')
df = pd.read_html(response.text, attrs={'class':'treasuries-table'})[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                                        Entity  Country  ... Value Today % of 21m
0                                          NaN      NaN  ...      266019   1.267%
1                                MicroStrategy      NaN  ...      129218   0.615%
2                                   Tesla, Inc      NaN  ...       42902   0.204%
3                      Galaxy Digital Holdings      NaN  ...       16400   0.078%
4                          Voyager Digital LTD      NaN  ...       12260   0.058%
5                Marathon Digital Holdings Inc      NaN  ...        9373   0.045%
6                                  Square Inc.      NaN  ...        8027   0.038%
7                            Hut 8 Mining Corp      NaN  ...        6460   0.031%
8                        Riot Blockchain, Inc.      NaN  ...        6320    0.03%
9                             Bitfarms Limited      NaN  ...        5646   0.027%
10                             Core Scientific      NaN  ...        5296   0.025%
11                       Coinbase Global, Inc.      NaN  ...        4482   0.021%
12                            Bitcoin Group SE      NaN  ...        3947   0.019%
13                             Hive Blockchain      NaN  ...        2832   0.013%
14                         Argo Blockchain PLC      NaN  ...        2685   0.013%
15                               NEXON Co. Ltd      NaN  ...        1717   0.008%
16                         Exodus Movement Inc      NaN  ...        1300   0.006%
17                 Brooker Group's BROOK (BKK)      NaN  ...        1150   0.005%
18                                       Meitu      NaN  ...         941   0.004%
19                           Bit Digital, Inc.      NaN  ...         832   0.004%
20                    Digihost Technology Inc.      NaN  ...         797   0.004%
21                    BIGG Digital Assets Inc.      NaN  ...         575   0.003%
22               DMG Blockchain Solutions Inc.      NaN  ...         432   0.002%
23                              CleanSpark Inc      NaN  ...         420   0.002%
24                    Cypherpunk Holdings Inc.      NaN  ...         386   0.002%
25            Advanced Bitcoin Technologies AG      NaN  ...         254   0.001%
26                                    DigitalX      NaN  ...         216   0.001%
27                      Neptune Digital Assets      NaN  ...         194   0.001%
28  Cathedra Bitcoin Inc (Fortress Blockchain)      NaN  ...         169   0.001%
29                          MercadoLibre, Inc.      NaN  ...         150   0.001%
30                           LQwD FinTech Corp      NaN  ...         139   0.001%
31                          Banxa Holdings Inc      NaN  ...         136   0.001%
32                              Phunware, Inc.      NaN  ...         127   0.001%
33                                   BTCS Inc.      NaN  ...          90     0.0%
34                                  FRMO Corp.      NaN  ...          63     0.0%
35        Canada Computational Unlimited Corp.      NaN  ...          37     0.0%
36                                   Metromile      NaN  ...          25     0.0%
37                              MOGO Financing      NaN  ...          18     0.0%
38                  Net Holding Anonim Sirketi      NaN  ...           3     0.0%

[39 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

hover over the element in inspect window the right click on mouse > copy > Copy XPath

I am not sure which scraper are you using but it return data to me using beautiful soup

```
sp = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class":"treasuries-table"})[1]
```

this returns

```
 Entity Country Symbol:Exchange Filings & Sources # of BTC Value Today % of 21m    MicroStrategy    MSTR:NADQ Filing | News 129,218 129218 0.615%   Tesla, Inc    TSLA:NADQ Filing | News 42,902 42902 0.204%   Galaxy Digital Holdings    BRPHF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 16,400 16400 0.078%   Voyager Digital LTD    VOYG:TSX Filing | News 12,260 12260 0.058%   Marathon Digital Holdings Inc    MARA:NADQ Filing | News 9,373 9373 0.045%   Square Inc.    SQ:NYSE Filing | News 8,027 8027 0.038%   Hut 8 Mining Corp    HUT:NASDAQ Filing | News 6,460 6460 0.031%   Riot Blockchain, Inc.    RIOT:NADQ Filing | News 6,320 6320 0.03%   Bitfarms Limited    BITF:NASDAQ Filing | News 5,646 5646 0.027%   Core Scientific    CORZ:NASDAQ Filing | News 5,296 5296 0.025%   Coinbase Global, Inc.    COIN:NADQ Filing | News 4,482 4482 0.021%   Bitcoin Group SE    BTGGF:TCMKTS Filing | News 3,947 3947 0.019%   Hive Blockchain    HIVE:NASDAQ Filing | News 2,832 2832 0.013%   Argo Blockchain PLC    ARBKF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 2,685 2685 0.013%   NEXON Co. Ltd    NEXOF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 1,717 1717 0.008%   Exodus Movement Inc    :OTCMKTS Filing | News 1,300 1300 0.006%   Brooker Group's BROOK (BKK)    BROOK:BKK Filing | News 1,150 1150 0.005%   Meitu    HKD:HKG Filing | News 941 941 0.004%   Bit Digital, Inc.    BTBT:NASDAQ Filing | News 832 832 0.004%   Digihost Technology Inc.    
HSSHF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 797 797 0.004%   BIGG Digital Assets Inc.    BBKCF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 575 575 0.003%   DMG Blockchain Solutions Inc.    DMGGF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 432 432 0.002%   
CleanSpark Inc    CLSK:NASDAQ Filing | News 420 420 0.002%   Cypherpunk Holdings Inc.    HODL:OTCMKTS Filing | News 386 386 0.002%   Advanced Bitcoin Technologies AG    ABT:DUS Filing | News 254 254 0.001%   DigitalX    DGGXF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 216 216 0.001%   Neptune Digital Assets    NPPTF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 194 194 0.001%   Cathedra Bitcoin Inc (Fortress Blockchain)    CBIT:CVE Filing | News 169 169 0.001%   MercadoLibre, Inc.    MELI:NADQ Filing | News 150 150 0.001%   LQwD 
FinTech Corp    OTC:INLAF Filing | News 139 139 0.001%   Banxa Holdings Inc    BNXAF:OTCMKTS Filing | News 136 136 0.001%   Phunware, Inc.    PHUN:NASDAQ Filing | News 127 127 0.001%   BTCS Inc.  
  BTCS:OTCMKTS Filing | News 90 90 0.0%   FRMO Corp.    FRMO:OTCMKTS Filing | News 63 63 0.0%   Canada Computational Unlimited Corp.    SATO:TSXV Filing | News 37 37 0.0%   Metromile    MILE:NASDAQ Filing | News 25 25 0.0%   MOGO Financing    MOGO:Nasdaq Filing | News 18 18 0.0%   Net Holding 
Anonim Sirketi    NTHOL TI:IST Filing | News 3 3 0.0%       Totals: 266019 266019  1.267%
```

anyway just add [1] to display the second element of the list as there are two tables with the same class name, the first one with 0 index and the second one 1 index
for selenium use

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, value="treasuries-table")[1]
```

hope it helps

Comment: It gave me `/html/body/div[4]/div/table[3]` but it renders no results. I've noticed that there are whitespaces in between the html elements in the source code, can it be the reason why it does not work? Even `//body` gives no results in [my xpath tester](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: check my answer edit

Comment: Python, selenium. I've not yet figured out how to find this element without relying on selecting with xpaths. A hint how to do this in selenium is welcome ;-) Or I could perhaps rewrite it with beautiful soup ...

Comment: both are good for not so large data, just type driver.find_elements(By. and hit ctrl+space it will show you various choices to use with for eg
you can use css selectors in chain using By.CSS_SELECTOR value=".css_selector1.class_name"
Class name as -> By.CLASS_NAME, value="class_name"
ID, TAG_NAME, you just need to use xpath when item is hard to locate otherwise you can rely on other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
table[class*="treasuries-table"]
```

or

```
table[class*=" treasuries-table "]
```

Comment: My [xpath tester](https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html) spits out `An error has occured: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'table[class*=" treasuries-table "]' is not a valid XPath expression.` when I try your solutions. I think it does not understand `*=`.

Comment: This is not XPath

Comment: Yes, I misread. I leave it there if someone prefer to use the CSS selector instead of xpath, as it's easier to use with JS, at least in my opinion.