# Add _blank to all external links

Tags: php, uri, str-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)
>   [Parse All Links That Contain A Specific Word In "href" Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208240/php-parse-all-links-that-contain-a-speciffic-word-in-href-tag/8209363#8209363)

I'm using the following function to add _blank to all the links on my website.

```
function targetBlank($text) {
  $return = str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank"', $text);
  return $return;
}
```

I'm looking for a solution to apply this function only on external links (not on my domain) instead of all links.

Comment: This will fail for a tag like `<a target="top"...`; you'll wind up with `<a target="_blank" target="top"...` etc. This will also break `<abbr>`, `<applet>`, `<address>` and any other tags that start with 'a'.

Comment: If you want to fix the <abbr>, <applet>... error mentioned above, do: `return str_replace('<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $text);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempted solution that relies on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

```
function targetBlank($text) {
  if( strpos( $text, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) === false )
      return str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank"', $text);
  return $text;
}
```

Untested, but it should work.  @meager is also correct in that this will produce malformed anchor tags if that tag already has a target defined, however, since it will only operate on html strings that you pass in, then `<abbr>` and so on should be safe as long as you only pass strings with anchor tags in them.

Comment: What if there already is a target attribute? Wouldn't a regex be better?

Comment: @tntu Correct, which I pointed out in the answer (~6 months ago).